# In what way is the solve function using two matrices to derive coefficient estimates?

Tags: r

The function solve appears to take two matrices to derive estimates. Can someone explain in detail what is it doing with the two matrices? Why was there a need for c(rep(1,n) ?

```
demo.data <-data.frame(y=c(1.55,0.42,1.29,0.73,0.76,-1.09,1.41,-0.32),x1=c(1.13,-0.73,0.12,0.52,-0.54,-1.15,0.20,-1.09),x2=c(1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1))
demo.data

Y <- matrix(demo.data$y) 
Y
n <- nrow(demo.data)
n
X <- matrix(c(rep(1,n),demo.data$x1,demo.data$x2),nrow=n,ncol=3)
X

BETA.HAT <- solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%Y
BETA.HAT
```

Comment: `rep(1, n)` is creating a column for the "intercept" term you've probably seen in other regressions. The rest is all about the linear algebra solution to least squares regression, you should be able to find plenty of info about that e.g. https://medium.com/@andrew.chamberlain/the-linear-algebra-view-of-least-squares-regression-f67044b7f39b

Comment: i highly suggest using the internal function `model.matrix` to create your model matrices. `X <- model.matrix(y ~ x1 + x2, data =  demo.data)`. As for `solve` it is inverting your matrix. Similar to `solve(t(X) %*% X, diag(n = ncol(X)))`.